# Rake Test Failure. Why am I getting these errors and how do I fix them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, unit-testing

I'm going through some Rails learning material where the focus is about validation and unit testing. I'm getting the following test errors and could could do with some help on how to fix this. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
rake test
Run options: --seed 54556

# Running tests:

.F.....F

Finished tests in 0.447052s, 17.8950 tests/s, 33.5531 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product [/depot/test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:26]:
"Product.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2

  2) Failure:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product [/depot/test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:45]:
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

8 tests, 15 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Here are the contents of products_controller_test.rb file:

```
1. require 'test_helper'
2.
3. class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
4.   setup do
5.     @product = products (:one)
6.     @update = {
7.       title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
8.       description: 'Wibbles are fun!',
9.       image_url: 'lorem.jpg',
10.       price: 19.95
11.     }
12.  end
...
25. test "should create product" do
26.    assert_difference('Product.count') do
27.      post :create, product: @update
28.    end
...
43. test "should update product" do
44.    put :update, id: @product.to_param, product: @update
45.    assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
46. end
...
55. end
```

Here is the Controller (products_controller.rb):

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
end
```

Here's the Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
        with: %r{\. (gif|jpg|png)\z}i,
        message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
    }
end
```

And here is the model test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
end
end
```

Comment: What happens when you actually try to create a new product on the site? Does it work or fail?  It would be easiest to troubleshoot if you posted a link to the git repo.

Comment: @RockwellRice if I try to create a product I get an error message for the image. I've added the project to github (https://github.com/lb0202/depot).

Comment: I am viewing this on my phone so I am unsure if there really is or not.  If there is a space in the producr_controller_test.rb between "products" and "(:one) connect them and see if the test passes. Looks like line 5.

Comment: Yes, there was a space but that wasn't the problem. I've managed to narrowed it down a bit further. The problem seems to be in the Model. More precisely somewhere here:
    `validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\. (gif|jpg|png)\z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
    }`
If I comment this out it passes the test. However, I still don't know what's the problem with that. PS.: Sorry for the format, having issues with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

@RockwellRice I managed to solve! In the model, **instead of:**

```
  with: %r{\. (gif|jpg|png)\z}i,
```

**It is:**

```
  with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\z}i,
```

There is a space after the dot in front of the first backslash which shouldn't be there. Once the space is removed it works! In the book it looks like the space is supposed to be there but it isn't.